# breakpoint in ISR

Tags: embedded

is it legal/possible to set a breakpoint inside an ISR? Or this is rather hardware specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly legal, but there may be some hiccups due to other ISR's not being fired in time, eg USB.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give an example? Does this require any additional hardware, for example JTAG, as I understand it, setting BP inside the interrupt handler requires to "freeze" the CPU temporarily.

Comment: On my CortexM3, when a breakpoint is hit, everything stops (particularly timers), but not the systick timer. As for USB, the host expects the device to respond frequently (1 - 1000ms) to polls. If you are halting the 'CPU' and you get such a request, it is likely the host will disconnect the device. That said, the same could happen when debugging anywhere, not just the ISR.

Comment: @Mark:  Typically a breakpoint stops the processor core in any case.  Your hardware may support features to stop peripheral timer/counters and watchdog timers while the core is halted.  If you are using an operating system such as Linux, or VxWorks, with a fully OS aware debugger, a breakpoint may optionally be thread or process specific allowing other threads or processes to run.